# getElementById returns null? (with Vue)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I tried to find the answer, but no success.

```
window.onload = function() {
   console.log(document.getElementById('#sell'));
   if(document.getElementById('#sell')){
      alert('jo');
      //Init for Vue
   }
}
```

It works with jQuery but not with vanilla JS why?

```
console.log(document.getElementById('#sell'));
```

Result returns `NULL`.

jQuery example:

```
if ( $( "#sell" ).length ) {
   const app = new Vue({
          el: '#sell',
          components: { sellPicture }
   });
}
```

In my sell.blade.php it looks like that

```
... 
<div id="sell">
    <sell-picture></sell-picture>
</div>
....
```

My script is added before /body

Just a side question. I need jQuery for Bootstrap, is it bad to use it also in Vue if I don't change the DOM with it?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('sell')` without hashtag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove # from the id param like below

```
window.onload = function() {
   console.log(document.getElementById('sell'));
   if(document.getElementById('sell')){
      alert('jo');
      //Init for Vue
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you!! My mistake! I forgot to how to use vanilla js. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('#sell')` does not require a `#` to identify Ids. That is the syntax you would use in a jQuery selector, but a DOM selector will literally take the string and match it against the ID attribute value. The same goes for `document.getElementByClassName()`, where you would not need a `.` to identify the class.

The Mozilla MDN documentation gives an example of this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

This should work:

```
window.onload = function() {
   console.log(document.getElementById('sell'));
   if(document.getElementById('sell')){
      alert('jo');
      //Init for Vue
   }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Please try to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){ console.log($("#sell")); });
```

Comment: the OP already stated _"It works with jQuery"_, so how would this answer help?

Comment: I believe the OP added that after this comment. While this answer is unclear, the comment is unneeded.

Comment: Thanks anyway! @Jaswinder